# How to hide/mask sensitive data from airflow connections and variable section?

Tags: python, airflow

We have many AWS connection string in apache airflow and anyone can see our access keys and secret keys in airflow webserver connections section. How to hide or mask sensitive data in airflow webserver?

[image]

We have already enabled authentication true in airflow configuration so it won't allow unauthorized users. But I don't want to show my keys in web view.

Answer (score 9):

For the Airflow Variables section, Airflow will automatically hide any values if the variable name contains `secret` or `password`.  The check for this value is case-insensitive, so the value of a variable with a name containing `SECRET` will also be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround for this use case. There is an option in airflow AWSHook, We can pass key path in connection string instead of secret key and access key.

[image]

> /root/keys/aws_keys

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret key>
region=<region>

[s3_prod]
aws_access_key_id=<access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret key>
region=<region>
```

How it works? First it will check extra params in connection string for any aws keys added if not then it will check key path(s3_config_file). if both options are not available then it will look credentials from boto.cfg file. So now no need to expose any keys explicitly in UI :)

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP authentication module provides the ability to specify a group based filter for a group which will be admins, and able to see that menu, and the rest.

See [the documentation under security](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html).

> The superuser_filter and data_profiler_filter are optional. If defined, these configurations allow you to specify LDAP groups that users must belong to in order to have superuser (admin) and data-profiler permissions. If undefined, all users will be superusers and data profilers.

Note that data-profilers can run adhoc queries on any defined connection. They cannot see the admin menu however. You may not want a group of users to be able to do arbitrary SQL or whatever over these, so also set that filter.

Any user can request in their DAG and tasks any variable. It's easy to put those variables in places where they will show up in the logs.

The database provides a way of storing the connection passwords, and variable values in an encrypted way, but that doesn't solve all your problems.

Comment: Is there any option to mask passwords from webserver? If I missed to enable authentication in my airflow configuration, then it will expose my keys to outside world right.

Comment: @MJK IIRC /admin/connection/ and /admin/connection/edit UIs do not load nor shown passwords. The field is empty. Leave it empty when editing and the update will leave whatever is stored as the password unchanged. Or enter something to set it. Do this on HTTPS (+ Authentication ?).
The problem of the passwords showing in the logs is still a possibility if someone is writes an operator that logs details from the connection.
Connection EXTRAs are revealed in the UI. This is bad for the s3 connection type, possibly others. E.G. `{"aws_access_key_id":"AID", "aws_secret_access_key": "AKEY"}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the AWS hook also allows you to put the access key in the "Login" box and the secret key in the "Password" box on the connection screen. If the hook finds that there is something in the login box it'll use that and the password box as the connection information, here is the snippet from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/8c9d3befb1453e60ad5565f6820908aeb1844326/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py#L90) for the AWS Hook:

```
    if self.aws_conn_id:
        try:
            connection_object = self.get_connection(self.aws_conn_id)
            if connection_object.login:
                aws_access_key_id = connection_object.login
                aws_secret_access_key = connection_object.password

            elif 'aws_secret_access_key' in connection_object.extra_dejson:
                aws_access_key_id = connection_object.extra_dejson['aws_access_key_id']
                aws_secret_access_key = connection_object.extra_dejson['aws_secret_access_key']

            elif 's3_config_file' in connection_object.extra_dejson:
                aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key = \
                    _parse_s3_config(connection_object.extra_dejson['s3_config_file'],
                                     connection_object.extra_dejson.get('s3_config_format'))
```

I've also found that you need to specify the `region_name` in the "Extra" box for the AWSHook in Airflow 1.9 otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide S3 sensitive data in Extra (connection param), you can set aws_access_key in login-field and aws_secret_key - in password-field

```
Conn Id: <your_conn_id>
Conn Type: S3

Login: <aws_access_key>
Password: <aws_secret_key>
```

p.s. host can be in extra: `Extra: {"host": "<host>"}`